# program in assembler that works with matrix

Tags: assembly, matrix, x86, masm

the problem is that i've never worked with assembler. And i just want you to review if the code is written correctly :)

the task to this program is:

1. to find a transpose matrix (save to arr2)
2. to find scalar product of 7th and 6th cols
3. to find an amount and sum of the elements of 4th row, that meets expectation (`a[i] <= b(-22) || a[i]>c(81)`)

```
.586P 

.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL 

_DATA SEGMENT 
arr1 DD -79, 59, 59, 93, -79, 84
    DD -51, 43, -50, -94, 23, 70
    DD -44, 97, -66, -17, 100, 82
    DD -83, 76, 1, 55, -20, -34
    DD -11, -51, -50, 55, -80, -28
    DD 58, -60, 30, 60, 90, -46
    DD 20, 82, -4, -93, -75, 35
arr2 DD 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    DD 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    DD 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    DD 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    DD 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    DD 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

rowCnt DD 7
colCnt DD 6
iter DD 0
arr1Offset DD 32
arr2Offset DD 24
arr2OffsetCnt DD 0
scalarProd SDWORD 0

var1 SDWORD 0
var2 SDWORD 0

varb DD -22
varc DD 81
condCnt DD 0
condSum SDWORD 0
compRes SDWORD 0

check SDWORD 0

_DATA ENDS 

_TEXT SEGMENT 
START: 
    ; Transpose matrix
    mov ECX, rowCnt
    lea EBX, arr1
    LOOP1:          
        mov iter, ECX
        mov ECX, colCnt
        lea ESI, arr2
        add ESI, arr2OffsetCnt
        LOOP2:
            mov EAX, [EBX]
            add [ESI], EAX
            add EBX, 4
            add ESI, arr2Offset
        loop LOOP2     
        mov ECX, iter
        add arr2OffsetCnt, 4
    loop LOOP1
    ; scalar product of 7th and 6th columns
    lea EBX, arr1
    add EBX, 24
    lea ESI, arr1
    add ESI, 20
    mov ECX, rowCnt
    LOOP3:
        mov EAX, [EBX]
        mov var1, EAX
        mov EAX, [ESI]
        mov var2, EAX
        mov EAX, var1
        imul EAX, var2
        add scalarProd, EAX
        add EBX, 24
        add ESI, 24
    loop LOOP3
    ;amount and sum of the elements of 4th row, that meets expectation (a[i] <= b(-22) || a[i]>c(81))
    lea EBX, arr1
    add EBX, 72
    mov ECX, 6
    LOOP4:
        mov compRes, 0
        mov EAX, [EBX]
        mov check, EAX
        CMP EAX, varb
        jg C1
        mov compRes, 1
        C1:
        CMP EAX, varc
        jl C2
        mov compRes, 1
        C2:
        mov EAX, compRes
        CMP EAX, 1
        jne C3
        inc condCnt
        mov EAX, condSum
        add EAX, [EBX]
        mov condSum, EAX
        C3:
        add EBX, 4
    loop LOOP4

RET                 
_TEXT ENDS 
END START
```

I tried to find a matrix arr1 and arr2 in memory, but the values that i found are not correct
[image]

Comment: I think `arr2Offset` should be 28, because this instruction `add [ESI], EAX` inserts values to the last position in each row in arr2.

Comment: Scalar multiplication should work fine for `arr2`. `arr1` doesn't have 7th column. So `ebx` and `esi` should be equal to `arr2` offset.

Comment: Also `ebx` and `esi` should be incremented by 28 bytes at the end of `loop3`.

Comment: Counter for `loop3` should be 6, program calculates only 6 rows. `mov ECX, rowCnt`, `rowCnt = 7`.

Comment: And 3rd part looks fine. First and last element are correct, `condCnt = 2` and `sum = -117 (0xFFFFFF8B)`

Comment: @Nassau how can i change rowCnt for 3 loop?

Comment: Use `dec ecx` after `mov ecx, rowCnt`.

Answer (score 1):

> - to find a transpose matrix (save to arr2)

The only real error here is that *arr2OffsetCnt* at 24 is too small because moving one row down in the second matrix uses a step of 28 (7 columns * 4 bytes).
The `add [ESI], EAX` addition instruction is not wrong per se, but it means that you can only use the code once and with the destination matrix zeroed!
It would make sense to define next equates that can replace those *rowCnt* and *colCnt* memory-based variables. With these equates defined, MASM can then do assembly-time calculations for you:

```
colsA equ 6
rowsA equ 7
colsB equ rowsA
rowsB equ colsA
```

You don't need the *iter* variable for temporary storage. You could preserve the value on the stack, but the better solution is to use an additional register like EDX. You got plenty of registers.
You don't need the *arr2OffsetCnt* variable for adjusting the address for the inner loop. Just preserve the destination address on the stack and once restored add 4.

```
; Transpose matrix
  mov  edi, OFFSET arrB    ; Destination
  mov  esi, OFFSET arrA    ; Source
  mov  ecx, rowsA
OuterLoop:
  mov  edx, colsA
  push edi                 ; (1)
InnerLoop:
  mov  eax, [esi]
  add  esi, 4
  mov  [edi], eax
  add  edi, colsB * 4      ; Same as `add edi, rowsA * 4`
  dec  edx
  jnz  InnerLoop     
  pop  edi                 ; (1)
  add  edi, 4
  dec  ecx
  jnz  OuterLoop
```

> - to find scalar product of 7th and 6th cols

The overlooked error here is that the first array doesn't have a 7th column. What follows is that you need to apply this step of the task to the transposed matrix instead.
Because in memory the elements are adjacent to each other, you don't need 2 different pointer registers.
Also, this code is needlessly complicated. There's no need for all those intermediate memory-based variables.
In 32-bit you should never use the (slow) `loop` instruction, and as I demonstrate in the below snippet, you don't even always need to use a dedicated loop counter. Here I continue the loop for as long as the (sole) pointer stays within the memory of the array. The end of the array is calculated with `OFFSET arrB + (colsB * rowsB * 4)`.

```
; scalar product of 7th and 6th columns
  mov  ebx, OFFSET arrB + 20  ; 6th column on the 1st row
  xor  ecx, ecx               ; scalarProd
LOOP3:
  mov  eax, [ebx]
  imul eax, [ebx + 4]
  add  ecx, eax
  add  ebx, colsB * 4         ; Same as `add ebx, rowsA * 4`
  cmp  ebx, OFFSET arrB + (colsB * rowsB * 4)
  jb   LOOP3
  mov  scalarProd, ecx
```

> - to find an amount and sum of the elements of 4th row, that meets expectation (a[i] <= b(-22) || a[i]>c(81))

Currently, you are processing the first array (source). I believe it would make more sense to apply this last step of the task to the second array (destination). The fact that the middle step of the task, through mentioning the 7th column, already forced using the second array, to me at least, points in this direction.
The logic that you have encoded can work but is over-complicated. And the value 81 gets treated the wrong way!
Instead of using that summary variable *compRes*, see how the below code just skips if the condition is not met.

```
; amount and sum of the elements of 4th row, that meets expectation (a[i] <= b(-22) || a[i]>c(81))

  mov  ebx, arrB + ((colsB * 4) * 3)  ; Address of the 4th row
  xor  ecx, ecx                       ; condSum
LOOP4:
  mov  eax, [ebx]
  cmp  eax, varb
  jle  .OK
  cmp  eax, varc
  jng  .NOK                           ; Skip if [-21,81]
.OK:
  inc  condCnt
  add  ecx, eax
.NOK:
  add  ebx, 4
  cmp  ebx, arrB + ((colsB * 4) * 4)  ; Address of the 5th row
  jb   LOOP4
  mov  condSum, ecx
```